# How to install io package for Octave on Mac

Tags: octave

I am trying to install the 'io' package for Octave on my Macbook Air, because I want to convert the .mat file into .xls file. However, when I try to install the package, the following errors appear:

```
octave:33> pkg install io-2.2.6.tar.gz
gzip: /Users/mlt660609/Downloads/io-2.2.6.tar.gz: not in gzip format
A(I): index out of bounds; value 3 out of bound 2
error: called from 'install' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m near line 102, column 19
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 146, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9
```

Anyone can help?? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: did you try to use "pkg install -forge io" ?